# Хочу обучиться php

Tags: php

Хочу обучиться php, но не знаю с чего начать. Посоветуйте что-нибудь.

Comment: Судя по грамматике, автору вопроса немного лет. Лучше учите паскаль. PHP - не более чем раскрученное словечко. Как язык он просто ужасен. Рекомендую подучить Pascal/Delphi

Comment: Обратите внимание на [вопросы](http://hashcode.ru/questions/tagged/php&%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/).

Answer (score 3):

Человек конкретно спрашивает за PHP, ему предлагают учить чего нибудь другое. Это тоже самое, когда человек пришел покупать в автосалон определенную марку автомобиля, а ему говорят: "А нафига Вам эта машина, купите вон мопед???!!!"
Что касается вопроса то вот сбоку можно увидеть ссылки на этот же вопрос, на который там явно ответили в полном объеме.

Не согласен в корне ни с одним из комментариев. В первую очередь необходимо быть программистом. Знание синтаксиса языка не говорит, что человек программист. И потом, если понимать основы программирования, а также Объектно-Ориентированное Программирование, то значение не имеет с какого я зыка начинать. Также необходимо понимать какие цели стоят перед человеком, который только начинает изучать язык. А безаппеляционно заявлять, что РНР это г... я бы не стал.

Из своего опыта - начал с РНР, сейчас осваиваю Java и Objective-C. Могу сказать, что те знания которые я получил при этом, с успехом применяю и в РНР.

Comment: Ну вообще всегда сложно согласиться с тем, что на тебе крест можно ставить в профессиональном плане :) Это психология, ничего личного.

По сабжу - php максимум дает понятие о "логических алгоритмах". Если долго учить только его, понимание работы компа с данными атрофируется. Я учил паскаль, потом паскаль + php, потом все остальное понемногу. Потом мне попался ASM и я две недели долбился в стену, зато после него все стало намного прозрачнее и понятнее. Причем да, я тоже думал, что язык значения не имеет. PHP - разросшийся шаблонизатор.